# Python - String deformats when running via SSH

Tags: python, linux, bash, ssh

I need to run some bash commands via Fabric API (ssh).

I have the following String in my Python module:

```
newCommand = command + "'`echo -ne '\\015'"
```

When I print this string directly in Python the output is the expected:

```
command'`echo -ne '\015'
```

However, if I try to run this command via the Fabric API the command is somehow modified into this:

```
/bin/bash -l -c "command'\`echo -ne '\015'"
```

Notice the '\' before 'echo'. Why is this happenning? The '\' is breaking my command and I can't successfuly run the command.

ps: The prefix "/bin/bash -l -c" is expected since that's how Fabric works with SSH

Comment: What is the command in the string supposed to do?

Comment: I need to start MySQL process in the background. Nohup won't work with Fabric (still a mystery to me). So I'm using screens. With newCommand I send the MySQL startup command to one screen I've created before. The 'echo -ne '\015' parte is to simulate the ENTER key pressed.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a valid shell command:

```
command'`echo -ne '\015'
```

Even if you add the missing backtick and single quote, it's nothing like writing "command" and pressing enter.

The context your command will be run in is basically what you'd get if you'd ssh and paste a command:

```
clientprompt$ ssh host
Welcome to Host, User
hostprompt$ <COMMAND HERE>
```

You should focus your efforts on finding a single command that does what you want, and **not** a series of keypresses that you could write to do it (that's not how ssh works).